# what is the difference between int(b) and (int)b?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between `(int)b` and `int(b)`?

Is it possible that the values will ever be different for `int(b)` and `(int)b`? If not, then what is the difference between both?

Can someone please kindly clarify?

My code:

```cpp
cout << "The expression is " << a + b << endl;
cout << "The expression is " << a + int(b) << endl;
cout << "The expression is " << a + (int)b << endl;
```

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve] not fragments of code.  All information should be in the question as formatted text and not images or links.  C++ is a context sensitive grammar (language) so code fragments without context are hard to interpret.  If you are _"...a beginner at c ..."_ why have you added the C++ tag?

Comment: Have a look here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast

Comment: _"I am a beginner at c"_ - C doesn't have the functional style cast `int(b)` afaik.

Comment: Your code is clearly C++, not C.

Comment: [Why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Voted to reopen. "needs details or clarity"? Really?

Answer (score 5):

Both are explicit cast expression.

- `(int) b` is a so-called *C-style cast expression* which will try to cast the value of `b` to the `int` type
- `int(b)` is a so-called *functional-style cast expression*. According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)

  > If there is exactly one expression in parentheses, this cast expression is exactly equivalent to the corresponding C-style cast expression

So in your context both are strictly equivalent. That being said the idiomatic C++ way as casting would be: `static_cast<int>(b)`. The good news with that last way is that is would not inadvertently ignore a `const` modifier...

Comment: Despite what cppreference says, they're not exactly the same. They're different when the name of the type being converted to has more than one word. Converting to `long long` can be done with a C-style cast, but not with a function-style cast.

Comment: @PeteBecker that's on cppreference in the sentence directly preceding the one quoted

Comment: @Cubbi — doesn’t matter, since it’s not in this answer.